# How to link a row of MySQL database table to another row in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I know it makes little sense... and i'm new to using MySQL...
What i'm trying to do here is, link one tables row to another tables row...
for an example there are two tables..
one table is for user registration and same table is used for login as well...
and the next table is for user posts.. like status updates and all...

here is how i want it...

```
user_log_info:-
id ( primary )
firstname
lastname
username
email
password

posts:-
id ( primary )
userposts
posted_by
date_post
```

so as you can see, i want the  `user_log_info` tables username to be automatically copied to `posts` `posted_by` row... And i have no idea how i can archive this...

Comment: Read, learn and inwardly digest this description about [SQL JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Sorry but this is not helping..!!

Comment: I don't think [s]he wants to join, I think [s]he just wants to get the information about the poster, which can be done easily through a foreign key.

Comment: Hi Dave, in your current questions, you haven't accepted any answers. If you choose an answer as the most acceptable or best for your circumstances, click the tick on the left hand side. It gives the answerer reputation and, if I recall correctly, you too.

Comment: yes Ashley Davies. i want to get information of the current poster.
Basically take the logged in users information from the table and pass that name to the posted_by row in the posts table when the user posts something.
I have tried a lot of forums but no answer. Is this done using php or MySQL does it for you just by assigning a foreign key?
If possible, link a video or explain a little bit :)

Comment: See my answer. Use posted_by as a foreign key, and whenever you need to find information about the poster, select them from the users table based on the ID supplied by posted_by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given nearly enough information to give a full answer, but I'll do my best with what you've given.

Tables

```
+-----------------+ +-----------------+
| users_log_info  | | posts           |
+-----------------+ +-----------------+
| int ID (primary)| | int ID (primary)|
+-----------------+ | int posted_by   |
                    +-----------------+
```

(I left off fields that are irrelevant to what you seem to want to do, I'm just simplifying it)

posted_by is an unofficial `foreign key`, or referencing the primary key of another table.

To insert, what you can do is along the lines of this:

```
INSERT INTO posts(...., posted_by) VALUES (...., user.ID)
```

Where .... is referencing all of your other information to insert

Then, to find information on someone who posted something:

```
SELECT * FROM users_log_info WHERE ID = Post.posted_by
```

Or if you want to find all posts by a user:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posted_by = user.ID
```

So, if Bob, who is User ID 3 wants to post "Hi", you might be able to do:

```
INSERT INTO posts(content, posted_by) VALUES('Hi', bob.ID)
```

And then when you are outputting the post you might do this:

```
post = (however you choose the post to put on the page)
userPosted = SELECT * FROM users_log_info WHERE ID = post.posted_by

print post.content + " posted by: " userPosted.Name
```

Essentially, the field "posted_by" is, to "posts" an arbitrary number, but you know that it links to, or references, a user. It does that by referencing "ID", which is the primary key of users_log_info, so that when you want to get information from users_log_info, is all you need to do is select the entry which has the ID that corresponds to "posted_by". I do recommend naming it something like `posterID`, however, for easier identification.

Comment: You can set up foreign keys formally and officially, which I recommend you look into in the future. Just search 'Foreign Key' into Google. If you're just trying to make something basic to help you learn, you should be okay with a system like this. (Just keep in mind to look it up sometime in the future)! Good luck!